# fixing datatables on boostrap form

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, datatables

I have a table that has many columns and I am using jquery-datatables. I want this table to fit on his container but the table goes over it! I am using bootstrap table-responsive and as you see there is a scroll bar in the buttom of the table!

```
<div class="table-responsive"></div>
```

It also is not getting smaller when the page is resized! can anyone help me ??

here is my plunker:
https://plnkr.co/edit/5LsDrsRPexXHpsWoSRFr?p=preview

Comment: It does not got over it, it gets a scroll bar instead which is an expected behavior with responsive tables.

Comment: I would like to not have that scroll bar and to make everything fit, do you think it is possible ?? thank you so much!

Comment: With that many fields, Yes and no. It would be possible but of no use as content won't be visible. So i won't suggest doing that.

If still you want to, you can limit the column width i suppose to a particular size something really small for all those columns to fit in.

Comment: the problem is that when i set the width for a column, my new width is not being considered at all by the browser, in fact the dimensions doesn't change!

Answer (score 0):

Just use table width 100% css. It will make the scroll able with fixed container.

```
<div class="table-responsive">
   <table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-condensed flip-content" id="topPerformerTable" width="100%">
      <thead style="background:#C0C0C0;">
         <tr>
            <th style="padding-left: 15px;"> Id </th>
            <th> Product Name </th>
            <th> Total Events </th>
            <th> Total Revenue </th>
            <th> Rental Time </th>
         </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
      </tbody>
   </table>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried this but width attribute on the table is ignored for some reason :/